# Send questions without code into review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Some of the tags I follow seem to have a chronic problem with off topic-ness.

For example, in the `[SSL]` category, here's the latest 6:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609839/duplicate-ssl-certs-on-same-server

  - CA operations question, no code, not programming related
- [Cross-Origin Request Blocked on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607901/cross-origin-request-blocked-on)

  - Same origin policy configuration, no code, not programming related
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606585/nginx-https-and-python-make-a-https-request

  - Nginx configuration, no code, not programming related
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604995/too-many-redirect-error-in-safary-https-redirect

  - Browser redirect, no code, may be programming related
- [Client certificate validation on server side, DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601989/client-certificate-validation-on-server-side-depth-zero-self-signed-cert-error)

  - YES! A programming question with CODE!!
- [How to create SSL certificate with Unicode characters in the Organization name (or other fields)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598872/how-to-create-ssl-certificate-with-unicode-characters-in-the-organization-name)

  - How to create a certificate with Unicode characters using OpenSSL commands, no code
- ...

Here's a tricky one that just showed up under `[SSL]`. Its a question on `cURL` commands, but the author brought it back on-topic when he mentioned its for a bash shell script. (I think he brought it closer to on-topic rather than drifting further off-topic).

- [cURL secure FTP access (--ftp-ssl-control works but --ftp-ssl doesn't)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613329/curl-secure-ftp-access-ftp-ssl-control-works-but-ftp-ssl-doesnt)

---

Some categories just seem to attract many non-programming questions, like `[OpenSSL]` and `[SSL]`. Others appear to have code, but they are really formatted configuration data. `[nginx]` comes to mind with formatted configuration data.

I've also noticed the same questions are not closed by the community. I find it odd because some of them are clearly out of scope per the Help Center.

Would it be possible to send questions from some categories into review when they don't have any code?

Is there another way to leverage the fact that a question lacks code?